# No redirect to login page with ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Im having problem with a asp.net mvc site. It seems that the "logging out" part doesnt work properly. I can login, no problem, but when Im logged out my code throws an error instead of redirecting to the login page. Im using the "starterpage" from VisualStudio.

my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms
      name="MyCookie"
      loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn"
      protection="All"
      slidingExpiration="false"
      path="/"
      timeout="1"/>
</authentication>
```

The login function:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I have a loop that every three sec. calls a function with ajax and when im logged out ( efter 1 min. as configured in web.config ) I get an error instead of the login page.

The function called with ajax

```
        [ActionName("StudentHelp")]
    [Authorize]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult StudentHelp()
    {
        var teacher = Membership.GetUser();

        using(var db = new DbEntities())
        {
            var studentUserIds = (from p in db.Help
                                    where p.TeacherId == (Guid) teacher.ProviderUserKey
                                    && p.IsHelped == false
                                    select p).ToList();

            IList<StudentModel> students = studentUserIds.Select(studentUserId => new StudentModel(studentUserId.StudentId)).ToList();

            return PartialView("_StudentHelp", students);
        }
    }
```

Any clues?

thx /Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error instead of the login page is because you haven't decorated  your `StudentHelp` action with the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute meaning that this action can be invoked by unauthenticated users. Except that inside this action you are attempting to fetch the currently logged in user (`Membership.GetUser()`) which will return null when there's no logged in user anymore (because his authentication cookie expired). And then in your LINQ query you are using `teacher.ProviderUserKey` but since the `teacher` variable is null you get a `NullReferenceException`.

---

UPDATE:

Due to a [known issue](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230) you might need to add the follownig key to your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />
<appSettings>
```

The release notes also suggest adding the following but so far this hasn't worked for me when I tested it:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. When I add the [Authorize] attribute I get the Error-page instead of the login page. Very wierd..

Comment: Did you look in the Event Log for the reason of the error? Also you may try subscribing to the Application_Error handler in Global.asax in order to intercept the unhandled exception and trace it to get more details.

Comment: As Darin said, I get a NullReferenceExeption on the Membership.GetUser() call. The problem is that I get the error itself when I instead should get the loginpage because the user if logged off.

Comment: I hooked up Fiddler and saw that the error is that its not finding /Account/LogIn even thought I specified /Account/LogOn. I cannot see in my project that I have /Account/Login anywhere. I guess this is a totally different question.